# Export Excel Selected Range to Json

Tags: json, excel, vba, export

I am trying to export a selected range to json and repeatedly run into the same problems receiving error messages "Sub or Function not defined".

```
Sub PrintJson()
Dim fs As Object
Dim jsonfile
Dim rangetoexport As Range
Dim rowcounter As Long
Dim columncounter As Long
Dim linedata As String
Dim path As String
Dim fname As String

Set rangetoexport = Sheets("Marketing").Range("C6", Range("C6").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))

path = ThisWorkbook.path & "\"
fname = "export.json"

Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set jsonfile = fs.CreateTextFile(path & fname, True)

linedata = "{""Output"": ["
jsonfile.WriteLine linedata
For rowcounter = 2 To rangetoexport.Rows.Count
    linedata = ""
    For columncounter = 1 To rangetoexport.Columns.Count
        linedata = linedata & """" & Replace(rangetoexport.Cells(1, columncounter), """", "\""") & """" & ":" & """" _
        & Replace(rangetoexport.Cells(rowcounter, columncounter), """", "\""") & """" & ","
    Next
    linedata = Left(linedata, Len(linedata) - 1)
    If rowcounter = rangetoexport.Rows.Count Then
        linedata = "{" & linedata & "}"
    Else
        linedata = "{" & linedata & "},"
    End If

    jsonfile.WriteLine linedata
Next
linedata = "]}"
jsonfile.WriteLine linedata
jsonfile.Close

Set fs = Nothing

End Sub
```

I am really new to VBA and just learning. But this confuses me, so any help appreciated.

Comment: What line does arise the error? Have you try debugging with F8 to see the exact moment it fails?

Comment: You need a function `clean_filename` or just use `fname ="export.json"`.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. It fails at ```jsonfile.WriteLine linedata````